# array.append(str(con_owned[i])) IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

So I'm getting a "array.append(str(con_owned[i])) IndexError: list index out of range" in my terminal and I'm kinda clueless any help?

Here is the rest of the code that was requested. I enter a number between 1 and 5 and i still get the error.

```
info = dict()

info['console'] = raw_input('The game console you own? ')
info['city'] = raw_input('The city you live in? ')
info['wconsole'] = raw_input('The console you would like? ')
info['rnum'] = raw_input('The number of consoles you own between 1 & 5? ')
info['rnum2'] = raw_input('A number between 1 and 12: ')
info['wcity'] = raw_input('Enter a number from 1 to 7: ')
info['float'] = float(input('Amount of money made per week (ex. 1.23): '))

if info['rnum'] >5:
    info['rnum'] = 5
elif info['rnum'] <1:
    info['rnum'] = 1

if info['rnum2'] >12:
    info['rnum'] = 12
elif info['rnum2'] <1:
    info['rnum2'] = 1

if info['wcity'] >7:
    info['wcity'] = 7
elif info['wcity'] <1:
    info['wcity'] = 1

con_owned = ['Xbox 360', 'Xbox One', 'Playstation 3', 'Playstation 4', 'Wii', 'WiiU', 'Xbox', 'Playstation 2', 'Gamecube']
con_owned.insert(0,str(info['console']))

array = []

for i in range(info['rnum']):
    array.append(str(con_owned[i]))

console_list = ""

for console in array:
    console_list = console_list + console + ", "

def calc_price():
    decimal = info['float']
    dollar_amount = decimal * 10
    return dollar_amount

calc_price = calc_price()

wcities =['Paris', 'Hollywood', 'London', 'Hong Kong', 'Dublin', 'Orlando', 'Dallas']
wcity = wcities[(info['wcity']-1)]

message = '''I have a {info[console]} that I play at my house in the city of {info[city]}.
I currently own {into[rnum]} consoles. I really want to have a {info[wconsole]} and play it in {wcity}. One day I would like own {info[rnum2]} consoles.
I wish I could make ${calc_price} a week, I could afford a {info[dream]} and move to {live}.'''

messageFormatted = message.format(**locals())
print messageFormatted
```

Comment: Hint: I bet `info['rnum']` is larger than `len(con_owned)`.

Comment: What is the value of info['rnum']

Comment: Using info['rnum'] = raw_input with a range between 1 and 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please mind providing the info dictionary? Because without it we can't replicate your problem on our end, which makes it harder to help you.

Although I'd bet that your `info['rnum']` is larger than your console list, since it seems that your program tries to open a list index that does not exist.(ie, con_owned[9] since con_owned has values for indexes 0 through 8)

Edit :
Just provide the entire program, because I just tried what you posted with 5 for `info['rnum']` and it worked without problem.

Edit 2 :
Here is the solution, replace :

```
if info['rnum2'] >12:
    info['rnum'] = 12
elif info['rnum2'] <1:
    info['rnum2'] = 1
```

with :

```
if info['rnum2'] >12:
    info['rnum2'] = 12
elif info['rnum2'] <1:
    info['rnum2'] = 1
```

You accidentally used rnum instead of rnum2 in that function.

Also, put all your raw_inputs that should be numbers in an `int()`

here :

```
info['console'] = raw_input('The game console you own? ')
info['city'] = raw_input('The city you live in? ')
info['wconsole'] = int(raw_input('The console you would like? '))
info['rnum'] = int(raw_input('The number of consoles you own between 1 & 5? '))
info['rnum2'] = int(raw_input('A number between 1 and 12: '))
info['wcity'] = int(raw_input('Enter a number from 1 to 7: '))
info['float'] = float(input('Amount of money made per week (ex. 1.23): '))
```

Comment: Added the dictionary info

Comment: Hm... Have you through about turning the result of your raw_input into an integer?
No that would throw another error...

Comment: I'd post all the code but it wants me to write mor eon the issue and I really dont know what else to say. :/

Comment: Okay, just to check, you ARE turning the result of raw_input into an integer somewhere if you want a number, right?

Also... Why do you already have values in con_owned? Isn't that supposed to be filled by user input?

Comment: I suggest that you try running the program again, but put `print info['rnum']` right in front of the loop that's causing the error.

Comment: I provided the entire thing. And I will try the print.

Comment: I found why! `if info['rnum2'] >12:
    info['rnum'] = 12`

Comment: Should it be if info['rnum2'] >12: info['rnum2'] = 12?

Comment: Don't forget to accept my answer$ if that fixed things! It's more rep for both of us, and that unlocks more possibilities on stack overflow.

Comment: I'm just getting more errors.
    `info['city'] = int(raw_input('The city you live in? '))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Orlando'`

Comment: Ah sorry, I was a bit overzealous. Remove that one int()

Comment: And the one around the console name.

I edited my answer to correct the errors.

Comment: Yea caught that one too and now... `messageFormatted = message.format(**locals())
KeyError: 'into'` I'm sorry

Comment: You got a typo here : `I currently own {into[rnum]} consoles.`
Replace into with info.

Comment: No problem, typos like that happen to everyone. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
info['rnum'] = int(raw_input('The number of consoles you own between 1 & 5? '))
```

Because I think that in `info['rnum']`, is not getting an int, and is getting an str.

I hope this helps

Comment: con_owned has 9 items and rnum can only be between 1 and 5 as instructed.

Comment: But between 1 & 5 is not mandatory... if you enter 100, it will allows and then you will get the problem ;) You are not validating the number

Comment: Yes but I enter a number in between 1 and 5 and still get the error.

Comment: I did your suggestion and im still getting the error. Thanks though.